# windows 8 stops working after gparted

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, gparted

My laptop (windows 8.1) has a big partition so i would like to spit it into two smaller partitions. I tried hirens boot and jumped into gparted (something i have never used before)

I resized windows partition (c:) and created a new partition, reboot, and my laptop cant boot

I am seeing in gparted
- sda1 ntfs recovery 300MB
- sda2 fat32 100MB
- sda3 unknown 128MB msftres
- sda4 is my original C partition
- sda5 is the new partition

I tried with Windows 8 DVD there are options to automatically fix but it did not work. I also tried with make PC fresh or something like that and windows told me it cant fix because the drive is locked.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. I stop playing with the tool now.

GParted 0.7.0 of Hirens 13

Comment: There are some partitions I've never heard of that are installed by default on Win 8. As of Vista there is the 100MB partition that contains the boot and BitLocker data, then there is the main Windows partition. Some manufacturers then create another partition containing the recovery image. You partition sizes don't add up to be the normal expected sizes (apart from the 100MB one). You may have to reformat and start again because your partition tables may be corrupt and startup repair doesn't work.

Comment: You could use a Linux LiveCD to rrcover your personal files to USB. You may end up wasting time trying to repair your computer when it could be quicker to restore it and put your data back.

Answer (score -1):

You should have used Windows to do the resizing. It would have been safer than using a utility that maybe doesn't handle well the NTFS format of Windows 8.

Try to delete the new partition and then reboot.

If this works, ensure that in the future the new partition follows the old,
and always use only the Windows Disk Management for working on Windows partitions.

If it doesn't help, see [Repair Install Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html).

If nothing works, you may need to use
[How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).
As this will destroy your data, use first a Linux live CD to save it (if required).

Comment: Another spurious downvote.